# Is it possible to add fixed content to a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview

I want to create a subclass of `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` that will have some shading at the top when the content offset is > 0 to indicate that the content is scrollable. (See image attached)
[image]

The way I'm implementing it right now is using the `UIViewController` that is the delegate of the `tableView`. I simply have a `GradientView` on top of the `tableView`, and I intercept `scrollViewDidScroll:` to animate the visibility of that top gradient.

My problem with this implementation is that it's not "clean". I want my `UIViewControllers` to take care of logic, and not to deal with applying gradients and stuff. I wish I could just drop a subclass of `UITableView` that will do that for me.

The challenge for me is that I can't figure out how the `tableView` could add to itself a fixed content on top of the scrollable content.

Another question is what method/s of `UIScrollView` should I override to intercept the scrolling event. Obviously I don't want the tableView to be the delegate of itself...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution on Apple's WWDC 2011 Session 104 video - Advanced Scroll View Techniques.

There is a whole section in this video about "Stationary Views" inside a scroll view.
According to Apple, the way to go here is to override layoutSubviews and put there all the code to position whatever you want - wherever you want.

I tried it and it's actually pretty easy and it's working as expected.

So for example if I would like a shadowed header on top of the table when the content is being scrolled, this is the code I should write:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self positionTopShadow];
}

-(void) positionTopShadow
{
    CGFloat yOffset = self.contentOffset.y;
    // I'm doing some limiting so that the maximum height of the shadow view will be 40 pixels
    yOffset = MIN(yOffset, 40);
    yOffset = MAX(0, yOffset);

    CGRect frame = self.topShadowView.frame;
    // The origin should be exactly like the content offset so it would look like
    // the shadow is at the top of the table (when it's actually just part of the content) 
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, self.contentOffset.y);
    frame.size.height = yOffset;
    frame.size.width = self.frame.size.width;
    self.topShadowView.frame = frame;

    if (self.topShadowView.superview == nil)
    {
        [self addSubview:self.topShadowView];
    }
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.topShadowView];
}
```

Comment: As i'm sure you know, you are allowed (and in this case encouraged) to accept your own answer :)

Comment: @rokjarc As I'm sure you know, you cannot accept your own answer within 24 hours... :)

Comment: Yeah, i was trying to be smart :)

Comment: @rokjarc As i'm sure you know, you are smart - dont doubt on that:)

Comment: I've encountered problems with your solution. Try to use it together with UIRefreshControl and when refreshing, contentOffset for the scroll view seems to be wrong.

Comment: Nice answer, Avraham. After reading it, it's so obvious. Kol hakavod :)

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to figure out a much simpler way of doing this then what Avraham did.

I use the fact that the UIScrollView calls scrollViewDidScroll: ever pixel the scrolling changes to set the object at the location of the offset. Below is my full code to keep a gray bar at the top of the scrollview as you move around:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 50.0, self.bounds.size.width - 15.0, self.bounds.size.height - 60.0)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:251.0/255.0 blue:251.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width + 500, 1000.0)];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [self addSubview:scrollView];

    UIView* header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, scrollView.contentSize.width, 40.0)];
    [header setTag:100];
    [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [scrollView addSubview:header];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UIView* header = [self viewWithTag:100];
    [header setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, scrollView.contentOffset.y, header.bounds.size.width, header.bounds.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: this one works for me, i just did some editing..and you need to add UIScrollViewDelegate..

Comment: You are correct, I thought it was implied that `[scrollView setDelegate:self];` means you need to also add the delegate, thanks for clearing that up for less experienced users.

Comment: This will work only if you want to make this changes from a UIViewController. If you want a self-contained UIScrollView subclass that have a stationary views - layoutSubviews is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using viewForHeaderInSection method of tableView for the shaded view(and also heightForHeaderInSection)... Make the shaded portion as a header.That way there is a fixed content on top of the scrollable content.

Comment: Not good enough because: A. maybe I would like a real header someday. B. It will still be at the top even if the content offset is 0. I want the shadow to appear only when the content is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define kImageOriginHight 300

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1{
CGFloat yOffset  = scrollView1.contentOffset.y;

// NSLog(@" y offset := %f", yOffset);

//zoom images and hide upper view while scrooling to down position
if (yOffset < 0) {//-kImageOriginHight


    CGRect f = imgV.frame;
    f.origin.y = yOffset;
    f.size.height =  -yOffset + kImageOriginHight;
    imgV.frame = f;

    //viewTableUpperView.alpha = 1.5 - (yOffset/-kImageOriginHight);
    //viewTableUpperView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    if(yOffset+0.5 == -kImageOriginHight){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
            //viewTableUpperView.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
        //viewTableUpperView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

}